# Android: onClick causing me to go back an Activity

Tags: android

I am trying to build a dynamic UI, but when I add the onClick method to the button whenever I push the button I go back to my previous activity. Any ideas on how to fix it?

my button's code: (the addMenu method is never run in the activities class)

```
<Button
    android:text="New Menu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/newButton"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:onClick="addMenu"/>
```

here is my addmenu code although no matter what goes in here(even if nothing at all) it still won't work

```
public void addMenu()
{
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.backLayer);
    Button newButton = new Button(this);
    newButton.setText("menu "+menu);
    layout.addView(newButton);
    menu++;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your addMenu method?

Comment: show the implementation of onClick method?

Comment: show your JAVA code please

Comment: u want prevent from go to previous activity ?

Comment: That can't be your addView method. `android:onClick` requires a `View` parameter in the method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> whenever I push the button I go back to my previous activity.

Sounds like your app is crashing and restarting... read the logcat, and you'd see something along the lines that your method signature is wrong.

`android:onClick="addMenu"` needs a method of `public void addMenu(View v)`.

Or just use Java to set the button listener and remove `android:onClick`.

```
findViewById(R.id.newButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) { 
        addMenu();
    }
}
```

Comment: adding View as a parameter fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
/**
* @param v  android:id="@+id/newButton"
*/
public void addMenu(View v)
{
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.backLayer);
    Button newButton = new Button(this);
    newButton.setText("menu "+menu);
    layout.addView(newButton);
    menu++;
}
```